# javascript not diplaying innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

ok I have been trying to figure this out now for 2 days and it just doesn't make any sense to me. so I have a registration form username, email, password and re-enter password. each input has JavaScript that on every keyup sends the users input to php where it validates it and will display "Good" in a div below password the div is "password_feedback"(this all works fine ,if I type in a valid password it will display "good" in the "password-feedback" div)

then I have JavaScript check to see what's in the "password_feedback". an "if statement" will display "good" in the "check2" div if "password_feedback"  ==  "Good" else it displays "bad". but this doesn't work it will always display "bad".

now here is the strange part I do the same for all 4 inputs ( re-enter password doesn't go to php just java) and "username" and "re-enter password" both work, email and password do not. if I change

var password_good = document.getElementById('password_feedback').innerHTML;

to

var password_good = document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML;    (username feedback instead of password feedabck)

then it will work for username. again the "password_feedback" will display "Good" like it should so that works.

in the javascript if I replace all the passwords information with the username information it will works so I know ity works fine. I cant even speculate why this doesn't work for password but does for username. iv tried everything I can think of, I have reduced the page so it only validates password. maby somebody out there knows something I don't.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#password_feedback').load( 'password-check.php').show();
 
 $('#password_input').keyup(function(){
  //username: is name of variable sent to php, form is name of form, username is name of input
  $.post('password-check.php', { password: form.password.value}, 
  function(result) {
   $('#password_feedback').html(result).show();
  });
  
 });
});
</script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

  function check_info1(){
    var password_good = document.getElementById('password_feedback').innerHTML;

        if(password_good == "Good"){
    document.getElementById("check2").innerHTML = "good";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("check2").innerHTML = "bad ";
    }   
        }


</script>
```

```html
<form name="form" onKeyUp="check_info()" onMouseUp="check_info1()"  >

    Username:<br />
    <input type="text" id="username_input" name="username"><div id="feedback"> </div>

    E-mail:<br/>
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email_input" value=""><div id="email_feedback"> </div>

    Password:<br/>
    <input name="password" type="password" id="password_input" value=""><div id="password_feedback"></div>

     Re-enter Password:<br/>
    <input name="password2" type="password" id="password_retype" value=""><div id="password_feedback2"> </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="login_btn"/>

    </form>
    <div id="check"></div>
    <div id="check2"></div>
```

```html
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "????", "????","?????");

 if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
     echo "failed" . mysqli_connect_error();
 }




$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['password']);
$check = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT password FROM users WHERE password='$password'");
$check_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($check);


if ($password==NULL)
echo "enter a password";


else if( preg_match( '~[A-Z]~', $password) &&
    preg_match( '~[a-z]~', $password) &&
    preg_match( '~\d~', $password) &&
    (strlen( $password) > 6)){
    echo "Good";
} else {
    echo "Not good enough";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the input type="password" to input type="text":

Passwords in browsers are treated differently, so you may have conflicts with seeing the results because of this.  You may try capturing the password field using keyup and the character used, but this is messy for a few reasons:

- not all characters are captured by this event the same across browsers (even subsets of characters may not use this event)
- you have to use a data structure and be sure it matches the field

You are better off simply using the $(input).val() function to store as your password every time the keyup, keypress, or change event fires.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but didn't work. I wouldn't think that would effect it, the feedback div that the java is looking at is displaying properly, the java just doesn't seem to want to recognize it

Comment: try the "change" or "keypress" event instead of keyup

Comment: iv tried all sorts of functions, and the retype-password is the same and looks for the same "Good" just a different div and that works.